# Can I upgrade the RAM on my HP Pavilion Elite HPE-112y

Tags: memory, windows-10-upgrade

This is a follow-up to an earlier question. I'm a bit of a newbie with computers.
I went into the bios which shows:
**8192 MB/PC3-8500

Memory Bank 1 thru 4 with 2048MB DDR3 SDRAM**
I assume this means that I have only 8gb of RAM on four memory cards (2048MB on each). I'd like to upgrade my RAM to at least 16GB. HP no longer supports this computer so they can't/won't help me. My OS is Windows 10.
Can I do a memory upgrade on this computer?

Comment: Specs say you can have a max of four 4GB DDR3 DIMMs: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01959711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  it currently has 8 gigs then.

This system can be upgraded to16 gigs, but you may have difficulty aquiring the RAM as its been discontinued.

A good way of solving this class of problem is to go to the Kingston or Crucial website and search for memory for your specific device - it usually advises the valid memory configurations and even exact supported memory modules.

https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/discontinuedmodel/61982/hp-compaq-pavilion-elite-hpe-112y  provides the details for your systems memory.